# how to disable border color change and click press effect in my UWP app?

Tags: c#, xaml, hover, styles, border

I have a simple game that I make it in the UWP style Now I want to disable the color changing when pointer Enters on button and disable when we click the button and IT color changes to   Black ? what should I do ? tnx :)

Comment: You want to change the style of the Button.